# Android Pie Chart Legend

Tags: android, legend, pie-chart

I can draw a pie chart using this:

http://blog.gafmediastudio.com/2010/04/01/draw-a-pie-chart-with-android/comment-page-1/#comment-1340

But now I want to show pie chart legend in pie chart view. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

So, you'd like to place the legend to the left or right of the chart? Why don't you add the necessary stuff in the

```
onDraw(Canvas canvas)
```

method? E.g. draw a rectangle with some strings in it.